# What is this tall light green grass growing with my bermuda?

Tags: lawn, grass

We know it's not crabgrass, but I'm not sure what else it could be. I just laid some scott's turf builder on the lawn, which caused it to grow quite a bit more than it normally does, so I'm wondering if this is a result of that somehow?

I'm in Dallas, TX (USA)

[image]

Comment: Is this in the wettest part of the lawn? Nutsedge is more common in the lower areas where water drains (my yard gets it the most near my driveway’s runoff to the lawn).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like nutsedge to me.

Comment: Agreed, this is fast growing (since it is so much higher than the other grass) and seems to be thick and bright green. I don’t think it is fescue.

Answer (score 1):

Most states have an Extension Service. I see that the one in [Texas](https://agrilifeextension.tamu.edu/) is based out of Texas A&M, and has [250 county offices](https://counties.agrilife.org/). One of the services they provide is weed identification.

Nothing on their [weeds page](https://aggieturf.tamu.edu/turfgrass-weeds/) is an unambiguous match to your photo, but there are a few likely candidates -- annual ryegrass, johnsongrass, rescuegrass, and a few of the sedges. Once you get seeds or flowers, it'll help narrow it down.  The additional photos on each weed's details page might be able to be matched up to your situation with a bit of detective work on your part.

They also provide a [weed identification service](https://aggieturf.tamu.edu/wp-content/uploads/Weed-sample-procedure.pdf) in which you take in a sample, or e-mail detailed photos.

In Nebraska, they even have a [weekly show](https://byf.unl.edu/) on public television. If they have that in Texas, maybe you can send in your sample and get a few of your fifteen minutes of fame.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar and I think that it's tall fescue. It's basically satan in grass form. We first noticed it about 5 years ago and it's now spread through over half of our yard.

"All too often coarse tall fescue is incorrectly identified as crabgrass. Tall fescue is a thick bladed fast growing and uncontrollable perennial grass that usually grows in clumps in the middle of a lawn. Tall fescue is NOT controllable without killing the desirable grasses surrounding the tall fescue."

https://www.organolawn.com/lawn-care-tips/crabgrass-vs-tall-fescue

Answer (score 0):

What about Roundup applied with a "wick applicator"? You wipe on Roundup to the blades that are above the Bermuda. If you have a limited area to apply to, then you might just get a foam paint applicator at least to see if this procedure works before investing in a special purpose wick applicator.